# Наибольшая общая подпоследовательность с восстановлением ответа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, warning

вот проблема

Даны две последовательности, требуется найти и вывести их наибольшую общую подпоследовательность.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных содержится число N – длина первой последовательности (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000). Во второй строке заданы члены первой последовательности (через пробел) – целые числа, не превосходящие 10000 по модулю.

В третьей строке записано число M – длина второй последовательности (1 ≤ M ≤ 1000). В четвертой строке задаются члены второй последовательности (через пробел) – целые числа, не превосходящие 10000 по модулю.

Выходные данные
Требуется вывести наибольшую общую подпоследовательность данных последовательностей, через пробел.

вот что я пробовал

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

const int N = 1002;

int x[N], y[N], a[N][N];

int main() {

    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    //cin.tie(0);
    //cout.tie(0);

    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> x[i];
    }
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        cin >> y[i];
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                a[i][j] = 1 + a[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
            else {
                a[i][j] = max(a[i - 1][j], a[i][j - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    vector<int> v;

    int i = n, j = m;

    while (i && j) {
        if (x[i - 1] == y[j - 1]) {
            v.push_back(x[i]);
            i--;
            j--;
        }
        else if (a[i - 1][j] == a[i][j]) {
            i--;
        }
        else {
            j--;
        }
    }

    for (int k = v.size() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        cout << v[k] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

во первых: выводит неправильный ответ(к примеру в случаи следующих входных данных 3 1 2 3 3 2 3 1, выводит 3  вместо 2 3 )
во вторых:выдает следующие предупреждения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while (i && j) {
        if (x[i] == y[j])
```